# Software or process that allows me to view a HTML file in a browser on my iphone when in development

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I'm currently building a website which is nearly finished but I have a number of hover effects that I need to check on an actual mobile.

I'm fairly new to freelance development and don't know how to do this. Is there a way I can store my site folder / index.html file onto my phone - it's not big (around 5mb) - and then launch it in Safari and/or chrome? From Dropbox, perhaps ?

The site is fairly bog standard with only css/html/javascript present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Once you've gotten the files on your phone in any way (such as Dropbox or email), open a web browser and go to the URL `file:///.../index.html`, where `...` is the filepath. The is the [`file` URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Comment: Many thanks. the file opens but the images don't open, I'm sure I read somewhere that this usually happens.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Images should work so long as they're in the directory you copied, the URLs are relative (rather than absolute), and the URLs use forward slashes as directory separators (not backslashes as is commonly done on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I upload to my own server, then view from the 'phone & various other devices, rather than having to load the site to multiple devices.

Of course, you are probably developing on `localhost` and since your 'phone probably connects to your home router by wifi, you can access your PC from your 'phone by its 192.xxx.xxx.xxx or 10.xxx.xxx.xxxx IP address.

Unless you are going to edit & develop on your 'phone or other device, why load the code onto it? Probably better to just leave it in on central place.

Also, Google & check out various sites that let you view your website (which needs a public IP address, so upload it to your server) and various resolutions, emulating different browsers and screen sizes.

If you are liable to be updating your code regularly, you might want to look into automated unit tests.